# Laravel lists with relationship for a dropdown

Tags: laravel, eloquent, accessor

I have two tables:

### course

- id
- name
- season_id
- teacher_id
- dates_id
- description
  ...

### course_dates

- id
- course_id
- weekday
- start
- stop
  ...

In the first table are the basic stuff for the course. In the second table i only store the dates of the course (i.e. weekday 1 for monday, start -> the time of beginning and stop -> for the ending). The course can have more than one date.

Now i want to create a list for a dropdown like so:

- course name (day, from-to)
- same course name (another day, from-to)
- another course name (day, from-to)

The name for the day i get over a little helper function.

How can i manipulate the parameter for the lists method, with an accessor?

Thanks for help!

course model

```
    <?php

class Course extends \Eloquent {

    protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

    //Relationship Holidays
    public function holidays()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Holiday');
    }

    //Relationship Teacher
    public function teacher()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Teacher');
    }

    //Relationship User
    public function bookings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Booking');
    }

    //Relationship Dates
    public function dates()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Dates');
    }

    //Accessor for Dates
    public function getWeekdayAttribute()
    {
        //???
    }

    //Validation Rules
    public static $rules = [
        'name'          =>  'required',
        'teacher_id'    =>  'required',
        'description'   =>  'required',
        'room'          =>  'required',
        'price'         =>  array('required', 'regex:/^\d*(\,\d{2})?$/'),
        'maxuser'       =>  'required|numeric',
        'target'        =>  'required'
    ];


    //Custom Attribute Names
    public static $names = [
        'name'          =>  'Kursname',
        'teacher_id'    =>  'Kursleiter',
        'description'   =>  'Beschreibung',
        'room'          =>  'Raum/Ort',
        'price'         =>  'Preis',
        'maxuser'       =>  'Max. Anzahl Teilnehmer',
        'target'        =>  'Zielgruppe'
    ];

    //Change Price Format Get
    public function getPriceAttribute($price)
    {
        return number_format($price, 2, ',', '');
    }

    //Change Price Format Set
    public function setPriceAttribute($price)
    {
        $this->attributes['price'] = str_replace(',', '.', $price);
    }

    //Unserialize Target Get
    public function getTargetAttribute($target)
    {
        return unserialize($target);
    }

    //Serialize Target Set
    public function setTargetAttribute($target)
    {
        $this->attributes['target'] = serialize($target);
    }
}
```

Dates model

```
    <?php

class Dates extends \Eloquent {

    protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

    protected $table = 'course_dates';

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Course')->orderBy('name');
    }

    //Validation Rules
    public static $rules = [
        'weekday'   =>  'required',
        'start'     =>  'required|date_format:H:i',
        'stop'       =>  'required|date_format:H:i'
    ];

    //Custom Attribute Names
    public static $names = [
        'weekday'   =>  'Wochentag',
        'start'     =>  'Von',
        'stop'       =>  'Bis'
    ];


}
```

Helper function

```
//Display Weekday
function showWeekday($id)
{
    $weekday = array(
        '1' => 'Montag',
        '2' => 'Dienstag',
        '3' => 'Mittwoch',
        '4' => 'Donnerstag',
        '5' => 'Freitag',
        '6' => 'Samstag',
        '0' => 'Sonntag'
    );

    return $weekday[$id];
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you already have? Also yes, you can manipulate an attribute for `lists()` with an accessor.

Comment: Thanks for the code. However it's still not clear to me how those dropdowns should look like / what data they should contain...

Comment: I want this format (i.g. Tennis Monday 12:55 - 13:55). But with an accessor i get every time the manipulated value, but i need it only for the dropdown. Better i create the array manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood you right something like this will do:

CourseDate model

```
public function getNameAndTimeAttribute(){
    return $this->course->name . ' ' . $this->attributes['start'] . ' - ' . $this->attributes['stop'];
}
```

And then:

```
$dropdown = CourseDate::with('course')->get()->lists('nameAndTime', 'id');
```

Comment: I'm not even trying to understand the OP question, because it's soo unclear, but I suppose you got it right - so just one thing: `get` before `lists` and it's good.

Comment: Why is `get()` necessary?